# How to end a JSON file with "\r\n"?

Tags: python, json

I have been working around with JSON files in python lately for an assignment and one thing is still unclear to me, yet Ive reached a point in it where I have to address it:

> The communication to the server is done through a TCP socket, exchanging JSON objects that end with the characters \r\n.

I have an issue though: How do I make my JSON files in python end that way?
Here is some code for a simple JSON object creation:

```
json.dumps({'test': 'EXAMPLE'}, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

The sort_keys is there for other exercises in the project. This object does not end with \r\n though.

### Overall, what I need help with:

What would "ending with \r\n" mean in terms of JSON and how would it impact the file itself?

Thank you and have a good day.
How would I do it in Python?

Comment: That makes no sense. `\r\n` might make some sense, but `\r\s` makes no sense.

Comment: Notably, `n` and `s` are right next to each other on the dvorak keyboard layout. A typo (from someone trying to write `\r\n`) is not unthinkable.

Comment: That's probably a typo for `\r\n` - there's no such thing as `\s`.  This wouldn't be part of the JSON data itself, it's something you'd output separately as a terminator/separator.

Comment: `json.dumps({'test': 'EXAMPLE'}, sort_keys=True, indent=4) + "\r\n"` what's the trouble?

Comment: Well -- you probably want `indent=None`; if the socket protocol specifies that CRLF is end-of-document, then having LFs throughout the data is likely to be inappropriate.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. My bad, its \r\n. Edited. Also @Jean-FrançoisFabre tried it however it did not work. Would that not be the JSON object plus a string, not the JSON object ending with \r\n himself?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy on the other hand, CRLF inside json content is valid, so I would hope the server can deal with those.

Comment: @PioAvenger that does not make sense. The result of `json.dumps` _is_ a string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That worked, thanks! How would indentation make the content differ though?

Comment: @PioAvenger, the thing is that `\r\n` is a (DOS-style) newline. When you set `indent=4`, you're saying you want your data split onto a bunch of separate lines, with indentation following those newlines. Thus, if the other side is reading only the first line, then `indent=4` means it won't get all your data.

Comment: @njzk2, *literal* CRLFs not being accepted is by no means unheard of -- a stream of JSON objects one-per-line is a fairly common format (hence, for example, `jq -c` being used to generate same).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Okay, that makes sense. Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r` is a means of expressing the carriage return character -- a control signal which sends the cursor back to the beginning of the line. `\n` is a linefeed -- a signal which sends the cursor down to the next line.

On DOS and Windows, `\r\n` (aka CRLF) is the traditional way to end a line of text. Presumably, then, this means that your software is expected to write a JSON document on one line, followed by a DOS/Windows-style newline.

```
socket.write(json.dumps({'test': 'EXAMPLE'}, sort_keys=True) + '\r\n')
```

Note that `indent=4` is not specified here, because setting *any* value other than `None` for `indent` means that you want your data split onto multiple (indented) lines -- whereas if your format ends in `\r\n`, that implies that the data is all expected to be on a single line.